# Router equipment and interface info in reverse DNS

Tags: router, juniper, dns, interface

Question about pages 17 and 18, of 49, at http://www.nanog.org/meetings/nanog45/presentations/Sunday/RAS_traceroute_N45.pdf

It is mentioned that prefixes and numbers in DNS (when doing traceroute) are specific to each vendor of network equipment.

An example is given of making sense of `xe-11-1-0.edge1.NewYork1.Level3.net`:

> - XE-#/#/# is Juniper 10GE port. The device has at least 12 slots.
> - It’s at least a 40G/slot router since it has a 10GE PIC in slot 1
> - It must be Juniper MX960, no other device could fit this profile.

How exactly does this work?  Do vendors provide special tools for generating and managing DNS records?  Or what is this based upon?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Large networks typically have a configuration management database (CMDB) software which will automatically generate DNS entries based on the networking equipment in that database. Smaller networks will configure DNS by hand.

There are no rules on how DNS labels must be named, the scheme mentioned in the presentation is just one which is commonly used, but there are lots of variations on this and also networks which choose a completely different naming scheme.